# "В пугающе(-)полупустом" раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

В пугающе полупустом зале (или) В пугающе-полупустом зале?

Comment: @М_Г Думаю, что метка должна быть не _пунктуация_, а _орфография_.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, так исправляйте смело (кстати, она не моя, я только добавил "раздельно-дефис")

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **в пугающе полупустом зале**. ***Пугающе*** — наречие (со значением следствия).

Авторское написание *в  пугающе-полупустом зале* соответствует двум прилагательным: *в пугающем, полупустом зале*, оно маловероятно.

1) **Розенталь**

17. Следует различать сложные прилагательные (со слитным или дефисным написанием) и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о/-е и прилагательного или причастия.

Наречие может указывать  **на степень признака,** выраженного прилагательным или причастием: ***максимально сжатые сроки; невозмутимо бесстрастный вид; умеренно тёплый климат***.

Чаще всего первым компонентом словосочетания выступают наречия ***абсолютно, диаметрально, жизненно, истинно, максимально, подлинно, последовательно, прямо, резко, строго, сугубо, явно, ясно*** и др.

Пример с наречием на ЮЩ: ***исчерпывающе полный ответ.***

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49#pp49

2)  **Для наречий с суффиксом ЮЩ**  степень проявления признака обычно  связана со  СЛЕДСТВИЕМ, выраженным глаголом: ***удручающе грустный взгляд (такой грустный, что удручает),  исчерпывающе полный ответ,  вызывающе развязный тон, потрясающе прекрасный вид.***

3) Дефисное написание сложных прилагательных с суффиксом ЮЩ встречается редко (часто это авторский вариант): Яркие зори на аспидно-сером небе и рядом **ослепляюще-яркий**, пламенеющий диск солнца, невиданного солнца с краями, которые трепещут огненной бахромой. [А. Р. Беляев. Чудесное око (1935)]

Но: Видишь свет — **ослепляюще яркий**?

4) У Розенталя: Чем ближе по значению элементы сочетания основ, **чем они синонимичнее,** тем заметнее выражается в них признак с добавочным оттенком, что дает основание для употребления сложного прилагательного **с дефисным написанием.**